# Accumulate promise values "functionally"

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

Say I have this:

```
function getAllPromises(key: string, val: any): Promise {

 const subDeps = someHash[key];
 const acc = {}; // accumulated value

 return subDeps.reduce(function (p, k) {

  return p.then(v => getAllPromises(k, v)).then(function (v) {
        acc[k] = v;
        return acc;
   });

 }, Promise.resolve(val));

}
```

is there a way to *avoid* having to declare a separate variable:

```
const acc = {}; // accumulated value
```

and somehow return that from the promise chain instead?

Ultimately the acc variable is what gets resolved from the promise chain, but wondering if I can somehow avoid having to declare it "outside" the chain.

Edit: the seed data for something like this looks like:

```
  {
    'one': [function (v) {
      return Promise.resolve('one');
    }],

    'two': ['one', function (v) {
      return Promise.resolve('two');
    }],

    'three': ['one', 'two', function (v) {
      return Promise.resolve('three');
    }],

  }
```

It's just a declarative dependency tree. Dependencies can be resolved in parallel; but may effectively block, as they run. For example, if I have a function like so:

```
function foo(one,two,three){


}
```

I want to inject these 3 dependencies. They can be sourced "in parallel", but `three` will be blocked until `one` and `two` are procured.

What is the `subDeps` variable? In the case of key="three", `subDeps` is `['one','two']`.

Comment: So a couple of questions to be able to answer this well:
(ONE) the initial run through `subDeps.reduce` (forgetting recursion for a second), you're passing in the initial object, and then thereafter you're passing in the new accumulator. So does `element[0]` of each sub dependency expect the parent, where the rest expect a growing object? (TWO) is the aray of subDeps actually sequential? Do they depend on being resolved in that order, or are they sibling keys that can be parallelized? From what I can guess, the sibling keys don't need to be in the order they're defined in, which is simpler.

Comment: Yeah the problem is that on any given level in the recursion, the top-level argument "val" could be anything, as I indicated with the "any" type.

Comment: Using acc as a independent variable, ensures that an object is there, which we can attach key/values to. But I am just wondering if there is a way to simplify it, out of curiosity.

Comment: But the question is: does `subDeps[0]` actually need the passed-in `value` (while `subDeps[1 - n]` do not)? While thinking about your problem, it looks like I can refactor it so that it doesn't require `key` or `value` as recursive inputs, but rather `someHash` and `subDeps`. This is only true if I could run `subDeps` in parallel, rather than waiting for each one to finish in sequence, though.

Comment: @Norguard you are correct, subDeps can be run in parallel; the way I have it now, they are pretty much in series. Good thinking.

Comment: So from what I can tell, the ultimate return value of that tree that you presented (which is `someHash`, or what it's based on with the module functions removed) would look something like `{one:{}, two: {one:{}}, three: {one:{}, two:{one:{}}}`, if you were to have a `four` with a `subDeps = ["one", "two", "three"]`. Let me know if I'm off, there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going out on a bit of a limb, here, in thinking that the whole list of `subDeps` for any child node can be loaded in parallel. In looking at the problem, deeper, I see no reason for that not to be the case. In fact, the only potential problem I could see is that some value *above* but not below this point could be a promise, and thus, you might even be able to strike the promises from this particular recursive function...

but...

Here's what I saw as a plausible refactor. Let me know if that's missing some obvious need.

```
const appendKeyValue = (dict, [key, value]) => {
  dict[key] = value;
  return dict;
};

const getKeyValuePair = hash => key =>
  getRefactoredPromises(hash, hash[key])
    .then(value => [key, value]);

const getRefactoredPromises = (someHash, subDeps) => {
  return Promise.all(subDeps.map(getKeyValuePair(someHash)))
    .then(pairs => pairs.reduce(appendKeyValue, {}));
};
```

In fact, if I'm right about this refactor, then you don't even need the promises in there. It just becomes:

```
const appendKeyValue = (dict, [key, value]) => {
  dict[key] = value;
  return dict;
};

const getKeyValuePair = hash => key =>
  [key, getRefactoredHash(hash, hash[key])];

const getRefactoredHash = (someHash, subDeps) =>
  subDeps.map(getKeyValuePair(someHash))
         .reduce(appendKeyValue, {});
```

If the root level of this call happens to be a promise, that should be inconsequential at this point, unless there's something I'm missing (it IS 6:20am, and I've yet to close my eyes).

Comment: subDeps can be run in parallel; in the actual problem at hand, one subDep might depend on another subDep running in parallel, but because promises are pretty nice, it would work out fine

Comment: I added some more info to the OP, for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array at second parameter to `.reduce()`, within `.reduce()` callback use destructing assignment to get `Promise` and object passed

```
return subDeps.reduce(([p, acc], k) => 
         [p.then(v => getAllPromises(k, v)).then(v => Object.assign(acc, {[k]:v}))
         , acc]; 
       }, [Promise.resolve(val), {}]).shift()//.then(result => /* result : acc */)
```

Comment: nice, I think there's an even more straightforward way

Comment: @AlexanderMills What is expected result of `acc`?

Comment: acc should be a plain object hash, with 0 or more keys

Comment: @AlexanderMills See updated post. `.shift()` is used to get `Promise` from index `0` of resulting array returned from `.reduce()`; `[0]` could alternatively be chained to `.reduce()` to get `Promise`

Comment: I added some more info to the OP, for clarity, thanks